# visual studio "unspecified error" how ever no exception is thrown

Tags: visual-studio, c#-3.0

I am making a program which takes data from a data base then preform a calcultion when pressing a button.

When you press the button for the first time no problems however if I press it two or more times a box pops up which inform you about an "unspecified error".

I have tried catching the exception however no exception is thrown.
I have tried debugging every line however I didn't find anything.

The error shows up multiple times at spesific lines and it seems that the compiler just ignores them.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVghQ.png)

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you provide more info. As of now there really isn't too much to go on. Post screen shots, or the actual error message at the least.

Comment: thanks for the fast response I have edited the question that you can find a link to the screenshot if you need anything more please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sulotion after look up how to use oledb and I found out that you need to use it like that so

```
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(adress)) {
                        connection.Open();

                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection)) {

etc etc etc

     }
}
```

isted of

```
 OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(adress);
```

the first way helps to dispose your code when it is not used.